# Auto post (user behalf) on facebook

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, share

I've been searching and haven't found an answer.
I've a website that has a livetracking service. 
I already use the javascript facebook share feed so that users can post on their facebook page their and others activities.

I wonder is at the moment (I know it had been possible in the past) is possible to post on user behalf. I already have a process to get a long lived token.

The goal is to give the ability of auto post when users start/end activities, informing their followers.

Comment: Make sure to read https://developers.facebook.com/policy

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that "restrictions". That's the main reason I'm asking this. Even though I know that some major websites/webapps/apps can do it.

Comment: Just because someone else does it doesn't mean it is allowed

Comment: Your point of view is correct. But the examples I'm try to follow are from official websites of important and known companies and brands...

Answer (score 1):

**Update from August 2018 on:**

The `publish_actions` can not be used anymore. It is not possible to post content on a user's profile automatically anymore. Facebook suggests using the `share dialog` instead, which requires the user's confirmation for every post. Facebook will show a window to the user for approving the post.
Example code for using the `share dialog`:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```

The full documentation with all parameters can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

---

A third party is only able to post content on behalf of a user if that user has granted permission for doing so.

The first step is to register an app, in case you haven't done it already:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Facebook will show a prompt to the user and ask him for giving permissions to that app. In the Facebook app, you need to ask for `publish_actions` permissions.
This will give you an access-token to publish posts on the wall of that user in his name.

For doing so you could use the Graph API:

```
POST graph.facebook.com
     /{user-id}/feed?
     message={message}&
     access_token={access-token}
```

If you are using the JavaScript SDK, the code could look similar to this:

```
FB.init({ 
    appId: 'insert your appID value here', 
    cookie: true, 
    xfbml: true, 
    status: true });    

FB.api(
    "/{user-id}/feed",
    "POST",
    {
        "message": "This is a test message"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Here you will find detailed information on the parameter and responses:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/user/feed#publish

Comment: publish_actions is deprecated https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/24/new-facebook-platform-product-changes-policy-updates/

Comment: Thank you for the helpful note @SandeepBalagopal. I have updated the answer and inserted your information.