# Create a post on facebook on users behalf using new Sharing Products feature

Tags: reactjs, facebook, share

My scenario:

I have an application within which users keep their own journals. For some of the journal records, i want to enable them to post to their facebook timeline.

It was rather straightforward with an old api (obtaining token and posting) but with a new Sharing Product, it seems impossible because its intended to use ograph data and backlink from facebook post to the page within the app but since the journal post itself is for logged user only, i don't see a way how could it work.

So, the question is:
How to enable users to share (actually, "replicate" is more accurate word) content from their authorization protected area within my application to their facebook timeline?

PS.
I am aware of solutions like: [Auto post (user behalf) on facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657678/auto-post-user-behalf-on-facebook) but that's an old api.

Comment: You can not create new content like this any more in any automated way, you can only let your users share links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create new content like this any more in any automated way, you can only let your users share links.

But you can point the Share button to any URL you like (parameter `href`), it does not have to be that of the current page.

Facebook will follow whatever you have set as `og:url` or canonical, so that would have to be the version without authorization then.
That would also be the URL that users clicking on the link in that post would be redirected to.